# Python - Measuring DNS and roundtrip time

Tags: python, dns, response

I am working on python script to measure the response time to DNS server and the response time for the get data from a web server.

The approach I took as follows

1. First measure the DNS lookup time using sockets module.Let's call this function A
2. Measure the response from web server using ping command in subprocess module. Let's call this function B

I call the function A first and then the function B in my code.

The solution works fine but I have my doubts whether this is the right approach.

The reason being, DNS lookup is being called twice (once in function A & then in function B). So the DNS lookup time in function B is always way less than the time calculated in function A.

function A code

```
                startTime = datetime.datetime.now()
                ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
                endTime = datetime.datetime.now()
                diff = (endTime - startTime).total_seconds() * 1000
```

function B code

```
    resp = subprocess.popen(['ping','-c 3','host.com'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out,err = resp.communicate()
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, the DNS response will likely come from a caching proxy, rather than the authoritative source, so it's not clear what use that information is. If you're trying to measure how long it takes to retrieve a web page, ping isn't really going to be of much use. What are you trying to achieve, exactly?

Comment: Thanks.I am trying to learn myself some network level programming and this is a simple task which I am trying out. I have changed from ping to urllib to calculate the roundtrip time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> DNS lookup is being called twice (once in function A & then in function B).

You can eliminate this issue by using the IP address returned by `gethostbyname()` for the subsequent HTTP request.

If you like, you can also split the timing for the HTTP request into the time taken for the protocol handshake, and the time taken to transfer the returned data. For the following code...

```
import socket
import time
import urllib2

hostname = 'stackoverflow.com'

dns_start = time.time()
ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
dns_end = time.time()

url = 'https://%s/' % ip_address
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('Host', hostname)

handshake_start = time.time()
stream = urllib2.urlopen(req)
handshake_end = time.time()

data_start = time.time()
data_length = len(stream.read())
data_end = time.time()

print 'DNS time            = %.2f ms' % ((dns_end - dns_start) * 1000)
print 'HTTP handshake time = %.2f ms' % ((handshake_end - handshake_start) * 1000)
print 'HTTP data time      = %.2f ms' % ((data_end - data_start) * 1000)
print 'Data received       = %d bytes' % data_length
```

...I get...

```
DNS time            = 1.77 ms
HTTP handshake time = 170.66 ms
HTTP data time      = 315.76 ms
Data received       = 242817 bytes
```

Note that the handshake time includes the time required for the TCP handshake, the SSL handshake (if applicable), the HTTP request, and the HTTP response headers, but usually also includes the amount of time the remote server took to generate the HTTP response body.